# Open cv Optical Flow Arrowed

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

Any expert on opencv to help!!
I need to draw the arrows to visualize the optical flow of lukas kanade method, i'm using arrowedline for this, but the arrows are not on the right direction and they don't seem correct.

Here's a part of the code:

```
for i,(old,new) in enumerate(zip(p0,p1)):
    a, b = ravel(old)
    c, d = ravel(new)
    #displacement
    v_x = int((c - a)/dt)
    v_y = int((b - d)/dt)
    scale = 100
    v_x = int((c-a)/dt*scale)
    v_y = int((b-d)/dt*scale)

    mask = cv2.arrowedLine(mask, (int(a),int(b)),(v_x,v_y), color[i].tolist(), 1)
    image = cv2.rotate(mask, cv2.ROTATE_180)
```

and this is the output:
[image: 1]

and with the quiver i got this:
[image: 2]

But I have to use arrowedline in this case, please if any expert can help solve this issue.
I've been trying to solve it since a while, and no result yet.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of [cv2.arrowedLine](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga0a165a3ca093fd488ac709fdf10c05b2) are `cv.arrowedLine(img, pt1, pt2, color)` and not `cv.arrowedLine(img, pt1, vx_vy, color)`.

- `pt1` - The point the arrow starts from.
- `pt2` - The point the arrow points to.

You may add `v_x` and `v_y` to `a` and `b`:

```
mask = cv2.arrowedLine(mask, (int(a),int(b)), (int(a)+v_x, int(b)+v_y), (255, 255, 255), 1)
```

---

I can't tell if there are any other problems, because you didn't post the values of `p0`, `p1`, `dt`, `scale`, and I don't know the format of the motion vectors and the points.

Next time, please post an executable code sample.

---

I created the following (executable) code sample for testing:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

mask = np.zeros((100, 100, 3), np.uint8)

p0 = [np.array([50, 50])]
p1 = [np.array([60, 60])]

dt = 100

for i, (old,new) in enumerate(zip(p0,p1)):
    a, b = np.ravel(old)
    c, d = np.ravel(new)
    #displacement
    v_x = int((c - a)/dt)
    v_y = int((b - d)/dt)
    scale = 100
    v_x = int((c-a)/dt*scale)
    v_y = int((b-d)/dt*scale)

    mask = cv2.arrowedLine(mask, (int(a),int(b)), (int(a)+v_x, int(b)+v_y), (255, 255, 255), 1)
    image = cv2.rotate(mask, cv2.ROTATE_180)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```